# Hive Query: Use specific database and show tables

Tags: ruby, hive, rbhive

I'm trying to execute the following Hive query:

```
"USE DATABASE1; SHOW TABLES"
```

Returns the following error:

```
HiveServerException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:13 missing EOF at ';' near 'DATABASE1'
```

Comment: A little more detail. I am trying to execute the Hive query above with the gem, rbhive.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the below command to get it done.

```
show tables in <YOUR_DATABASE_NAME>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not get hive to reproduce your error but this might help.

1. If the database didn't exist you would get a "Database does not exist" error.  So I rule that out.
2. Don't submit with quotes around it and make sure you close your last line with ";".  Use this code here:

   ```
   use database1; show tables;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but some simple database APIs don't support multiple statements very well.  Looking at the API, try something like this:

```
RBHive.connect(address, port) do |connection|
  connection.execute('USE DATABASE1')
  connection.fetch('SHOW TABLES')
end
```